# How to clean/delete a Maven project's "target" dir in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, primefaces

I had got some concrete included jars like primefaces in a very old project.

Yesterday i open that project in eclipse and decided to add everything with maven.

But even i delete concrete included jars, in target i both see primefaces3.5.jar(added manually a year ago) and primefaces5.0.jar whic comes with maven(as i need).

I need to clean/clear/delete? target dir in the project, i think.

The two different primefaces versions are conflicting and i am getting errors, when i search for error, i found out that i have two different versions at the same time.

Thanks

EDIT:

I manually delete project/Web Content/WEB-İNF/lib/primefaces3.5.jar,

and server started without errors

Comment: How about `mvn clean` command to clean target directory?

Comment: @suninsky i had "in eclipse" project->run as> maven build with goals clean install, but target is contains bot primefaces 3.5 and 5.0

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting your .m2 repository and download a fresh version of all the jars.
and rebuild your project.
you should not delete your target folder manually as this has to happen during maven clean install.
Also check if there any classpath settings existing for your project you should remove the jar files from there also.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use these commands to analyce if the dependency is declared multiple times or trancitivly.

```
mvn dependency:analyze-duplicate
mvn dependency:list
```

And as vikeng21 states. You should not have to manualy do anything manualy in the target folder.